# Кнопка меню телеграм API

Tags: python, kotlin, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет! Подскажите какими методами реализуется такая кнопка **Меню** в телеграм:
[image: кнопка меню]

в https://core.telegram.org/bots/api ничего не нашел по этому поводу.

Comment: я не уверен, но скорее всего это стандартная кнопка из телеграма. В которую автоматически добавляются все команды из бота

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Нашел решение, добавил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решить проблему можно двумя путями:** 
 
**1)** Делаем из кода через botCommand [ссылка на API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#botcommand)

**2)** Делаем из botFather: /mybots -> @bot_name -> Edit Bot -> Edit Commands

В первом случае кнопка и команды в ней появятся только при первом запуске бота, их нельзя будет изменить из сценария бота или же удалить. Придется лезть в botFather, для их редактирования.

Answer (score 3):

Это меню показывает команды бота. Оно настраивается через BotFather t.me/BotFather.
Заходим в BotFather, пишем команду /mybots.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем Вашего бота.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жмём "Edit Bot"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаем "Edit Commands"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсылаем в бота команды, используя такой формат:
команда1 описание1
команда2 описание2
и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и всё!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]