# Не работает кнопка в телеграмм-боте aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Нажимаю кнопку, сообщение отправляется, но ответа не получаю. Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    """
    ответ на старт команду
    """
    state = dp.current_state(user=message.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(TestStates.all()[1])
    await message.reply("Привет! Добро пожаловать! Выбери свой пол:", reply_markup=kb.gender_kb)

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "\U0001F9D4 Мужской")
async def if_male(message: types.Message):
    state = dp.current_state(user=message.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(TestStates.all()[2])
    await message.reply("Тут должен быть текст", reply_markup=kb.race_kb)
    wgender = 'Мужской'

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "\U0001F469 Женский")
async def if_female(message: types.Message):
    wgender = 'Женский'
    state = dp.current_state(user=message.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(TestStates.all()[2])
    await message.reply("Тут должен быть текст", reply_markup=kb.race_kb)
```

Код модуля kb:

```
button_gender1 = KeyboardButton('\U0001F9D4 Мужской')
button_gender2 = KeyboardButton('\U0001F469 Женский')
gender_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(button_gender1).add(button_gender2)

button_race1 = KeyboardButton('1')
button_race2 = KeyboardButton('2')
button_race3 = KeyboardButton('3')
race_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True).add(button_race1).add(button_race2).add(button_race3)
```

В командной строке пишет вот это:

```
INFO:aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging:Received message [ID:116] in chat [private:455671608]
INFO:aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging:Process update [ID:479176034]: [success] (in 1 ms)
```

Изменено: Нашёл ответ, всё дело в состояниях. Однако состояния эти мне всё равно нужны, что делать?

Comment: сделайте лучше заново, вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345315/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-api/1345342#1345342), будет гораздо удобнее и без ошибок

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 я писал код по тому гайду, что по ссылке

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас посмотрю, может найду ошибку